# Modifying a python list during zip and enumeration

Tags: python

I have a simple algorithm that calculates whether a list can be made non-decreasing with 1 or less number modifications. I'm not certain (or asking) if it works, this is about python semantics. I've summarized my 2 questions as comments:

```
def checkPossibility(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
    decrease_found = False
    for (i,val1),(j, val2) in zip(enumerate(nums[::1]), enumerate(nums[1::1])):
        # !!!! Why do i and j have the same values? They start at different indices
        print('%d,%d - %d,%d' % (i, val1, j, val2))
        if val1 > val2:
            if decrease_found:
                return False
            else:
                decrease_found = True
                # !!!! This update is not being represented on the next iteration (i -> i + 1)
                # i.e. val1 is not being updated in the subsequent print statement
                nums[i + 1] = nums[i]
                print("new nums is " + str(nums[i + 1]))
        print(nums)
    return True
```

Input:

```
[3,4,2,3]
```

Output:

```
0,3 - 0,4
[3, 4, 2, 3]
1,4 - 1,2
new nums is 4
[3, 4, 4, 3]
2,2 - 2,3
[3, 4, 4, 3]
```

I can't understand why in my output i == j. I also can't understand why my nums[i + 1] is not updating the subsequent iterations' val1 value, since nums[i + 1] is pointing to it.

Best guess is the zip(enumerate... is copying the two lists and iterating over those, which would make j accurate and altering val1/val2 through nums array modifications impossible. I can't find the source of this behavior though.

Comment: `i` and `j` correspond to the counters produced by `enumerate`. Both `enumerate`s start at the same number.

Comment: If you want the second `enumerate` to start from one, you can pass `1` as a second argument (`zip(enumerate(nums[::1]), enumerate(nums[1::1], 1))`).

Comment: Oh right, I'm splicing the list I pass to enumerate so they both would be copies starting at 0.

Starting at 1 on the second list was my only intention for splicing, so I removed the splice and just passed 1 as the 2nd argument as you've suggested:

```
for (i,val1),(j, val2) in zip(enumerate(nums), enumerate(nums, 1)):
```

However now val2 == val1 instead of val2 being one index ahead. Shouldn't it be pointing to the subsequent value still?


0,3 - 1,3
[3, 4, 2, 3]
1,4 - 2,4
[3, 4, 2, 3]
2,2 - 3,2
[3, 4, 2, 3]
3,3 - 4,3
[3, 4, 2, 3]

Comment: `enumerate` just takes whatever iterable you give it, and returns it with its own independent counter added. If you use `enumerate(it, 1)`, that does not mean that `it` will skip its first element; just that the added counter will start at `1`. If you want the "one ahead" iterable with a counter starting at `1`, you need to both slice and pass `1`!

Comment: …or you skip the first pair that `enumerate` returns. I.e. either `enumerate(it[1:], 1)`, or `islice(enumerate(it), 1, None)` would both yield the same result.